# ASP.NET Core EventLog provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, logging, asp.net-core

I have a project using .NET Framework ASP.NET Core 2.0, and want to implement logging to windows event log, like i read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Add log providers

```
public class Program
{
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
                logging.AddConsole();
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
    }
```

Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ShortCodeController : Controller
{
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public ShortCodeController(ILogger<ShortCodeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;

            _logger.LogInformation("INIT");
        }

        [HttpGet("{letters}/{digits}/{length}")]
        public string Get(bool letters, bool digits, int length)
        {
            _logger.LogError("TEST");

            return "value";
        }
    }
```

And it works for console,  I see my log messages. But i can't find that messages in event log using event viewer. Why?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `logging.AddEventSourceLogger()` rather than `logging.AddEventLog()` (as suggested in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#eventlog)?

Comment: `.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>` is  `.ConfigureLogging((logging) =>` in dotnet core 3.1 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-3.1#windows-eventlog-provider

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
logging.AddEventSourceLogger()
```

is for [Event Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#eventsource).

For the [Event Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#eventlog), you want to use:

```
logging.AddEventLog()
```

Comment: Its kind of related to this specific question and answer. Anyway, I've ran this from Package Manager Console "Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog -Version 2.0.0" and i can see it now.

Comment: The https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#eventlog link in my answer has a link to the NuGet package needed.

Comment: For `AddEventSourceLogger`, install nuget package `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource`.

Comment: @thepirat000 The context of this question is explicitly _not_ wanting `AddEventSourceLogger` so I am confused why you may have added that comment?

Comment: Updated link for the necessary NuGet package: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-2.1#windows-eventlog-provider

Comment: link for dotnet core 3.1 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-3.1#windows-eventlog-provider

Comment: Does the app running under IIS (unmanaged) need any special permission to add event log entry?

Comment: this works, but only Error level messages are added to event log. I set minimum level to Debug - no effect.

Comment: @AlexeiSosin You may want to create a new question for your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Install Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog from Nuget.

Include the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog on the program.cs file

Then `logging.AddEventLog()` will be possible and consequently you will be able to achieve your goal

Comment: I still can't find any log message in EventLog Viewer. Do you know what's the default EventSource name?

Answer (score 3):

"But i can't find that messages in event log using event viewer. Why?"

Unless you use a LogName and SourceName that your system recognizes, the event log will give you a meaningless error message.

This works for me against net5.0:

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                            {
                                logging.ClearProviders();
                                logging.AddEventLog(new EventLogSettings()
                                        {
                                            SourceName = ".NET Runtime",
                                            LogName = "Application",
                                        });
                            }
                         )
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).