# Logging to Eventlog from ASP.Net Core Web API fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm relatively new to ASP.Net Core and this issue may be down lack of knowledge. I'm developing a web service and I need it to log to the Windows EventLog for all events (Information and above) when in production. I've created an event source and a log using PowerShell:

```
New-EventLog -LogName CprNumberService -Source CprNumberService
```

I can't get the service to log Information events to the Windows Eventlog, only Warning and above works. All the other loggers works just fine and I see all log entries in Debug.

I've tried to change the settings in the appsettings files and that does have an effect on the Debug logprovider, but not with the Eventlog.

Here's my appsettings.json file:

```
appsettings.json
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
```

And appsettings.Development.json

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft" :  "Information"
    }
```

In the CreateHostBuild class in Programs.cs, I register the logs as follows:

```
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {

                // Remember to create windows log 
                // PS: New-EventLog -LogName CprNumberService -Source CprNumberService

                logging.ClearProviders();

                logging.AddDebug();
                logging.AddConsole();
                logging.AddEventLog(new EventLogSettings
                {
                    SourceName = "CprNumberService",
                    LogName = "CprNumberService"
                });
```

And in the actual code, I log as follows:

```
logger.LogInformation(LoggingEvents.CprSystemEvent, "CPR Web Service started up");
```

I am convinced I have a noob issue here and I've been Googeling a lot, but so far I've come up empty.

Suggestions and references are very welcome.

Thanks,
Bjarne

Comment: Have you tried using logging.AddEventSourceLogger()?

Comment: Please run visual studio as administrator and check it again

Comment: The .AddEventSourceLogger is for Event Tracing, not for the Windows Event log. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47773058/asp-net-core-eventlog-provider)

Comment: I tried to run in as Admin, it makes not difference.

Comment: the strangest thing is that the Windows Event log does recieve all event logged with LogWarning and LogError, but not LogInformation.

Comment: I'm not sure what the default level is for System, but you could try setting it aswell and se if it makes a difference. E.g "System": "Information"

Comment: I've tried that. Some result. The weirdest thing is that warnings and errors are actually posted to the windows event log.

Comment: Okey. If you have to option to use 3rd part libraries you could try setting up Serilog which have a sink for Eventlog and many many other nice features. 

https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-eventlog

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the log level info with the Filter property:

```
logging.AddEventLog(new EventLogSettings
{
    SourceName = "CprNumberService",
    LogName = "CprNumberService",
    Filter = (source, level) => level >= LogLevel.Information
});
```